# How to import modules in sequence with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to import the [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.VectorGrid), which requires [pbf](https://github.com/mapbox/pbf). The `pbf` library will provide a global variable `Pbf` and the author of `Leaflet.VectorGrid` simply assumes the existence of the global `Pbf`. So I will need to import these two libraries in sequence:

```
import 'pbf';
require('node_modules/leaflet.vectorgrid/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.js');
```

But the app throws an error `ReferenceError: Pbf is not defined`. It turns out that in `app.bundle.js` generated by webpack, the code of `pbf` library is placed behind the code of `Leaflet.VectorGrid`, regardless of the import order.

A fact that may be relevant: the `pbf` is a devDependency, not a dependency in the `package.json` of `Leaflet.Vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs an explicit dependency declaration in the library's `package.json`. So that webpack can figure out the correct import order.